# If I intend to use Hadoop is there a difference in 12.04 LTS 64 Desktop and Server?

Tags: installation, hadoop

Sorry for such a Newbie Question, but I'm looking at installing M3 edition of MapR the requirements are at this link:

http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR/Requirements+for+Installation

And my question is this, is the Desktop Kernel 64 for 12.04 LTS adequate or the "same" as the Server version of the product?  If I'm setting up a lab to attempt to install a home cluster environment should I start with the Server or Dual Boot that distribution?

My assumption is that the two are the same.  That I can add any additional software to the 64 as needed.

Can anyone elaborate on this?  Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Last I recall, Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu server are, at their core, the same. The only major differences lie in the installer (server edition is a low-graphics/text installer with the option to install packages common to servers, such as Apache, PHP, and MySQL for a web server; while desktop is a graphical installer aimed at typical users), and the desktop stack or lack thereof (server is what's known as a "headless" install, meaning it doesn't come with a desktop stack and can only be accessed through command line; desktop, of course, comes with Gnome/Unity). This equivalence also extends to the repositories - both desktop and server edition have access to the same repositories, and anything that works for Ubuntu desktop will work for Ubuntu server (save for GUI applications, which will need the proper libraries and whatnot, but they still work, provided you install the libraries).

For server setups of any sort, it's recommended to run the server version, because the desktop stack takes up a fair chunk of resources that are better left for the tasks the server is designed to do. A full headless system, though, requires you to be comfortable with command line. However, if you really want a graphical interface to work with, I still recommend starting with the server edition, then install a lightweight desktop stack, such as OpenBox or XFCE. That way, you're using as few resources as necessary for the convenience of having a desktop, and you only install on an as-needed basis, instead of starting with a bunch of unneeded stuff that you then have to try to rip out (it's easier to build up than tear down in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm genuinely doing lab work on this and will try both ways, and keep this link active.  Just so if somebody is looking they can get some information.  I see a pretty straightforward link here as well. http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/